# How to resolve "Exception while resolving variable 'name' in template 'unknown'." error thrown while logging API calls?

Tags: python-3.x, django, logging, django-views

My Django logging config:

```
def get_config(log_dir, level="INFO"):
    return {
        'version': 1,
        'disable_existing_loggers': False,
        'formatters': {
            'verbose': {
                'format': "[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s [%(name)s: %(funcName)s: %(lineno)s] %(message)s",
                'datefmt': "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z"
            },
            'simple': {
                'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
            },
        },
        'handlers': {
            'null': {
                'level': level,
                'class': 'logging.NullHandler',
            },
            'console': {
                'level': level,
                'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
                'formatter': 'verbose'
            },
            'django_log_file': {
                'level': level,
                'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
                'filename': os.path.join(log_dir, 'django.log'),
                'maxBytes': 16777216,  # 16megabytes
                'formatter': 'verbose'
            },
            'django_errors_file': {
                'level': 'ERROR',
                'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
                'filename': os.path.join(log_dir, 'django.errors.log'),
                'maxBytes': 16777216,  # 16megabytes
                'formatter': 'verbose'
            },
            'db_log_file': {
                'level': level,
                'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
                'filename': os.path.join(log_dir, 'dbs.log'),
                'maxBytes': 16777216,  # 16megabytes
                'formatter': 'verbose'
            },
            'apps_log_file': {
                'level': level,
                'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
                'filename': os.path.join(log_dir, 'apps.log'),
                'maxBytes': 16777216,  # 16megabytes
                'formatter': 'verbose'
            },
            'myapp_ui_log_file': {
                'level': level,
                'class': 'logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler',
                'when': 'midnight',
                'filename': os.path.join(log_dir, 'myapp_ui.log'),
                'interval': 1,
                'backupCount': 7,
                'formatter': 'verbose',
            },
            'myapp_apis_log_file': {
                'level': level,
                'class': 'logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler',
                'when': 'midnight',
                'filename': os.path.join(log_dir, 'myapp_apis.log'),
                'interval': 1,
                'backupCount': 7,
                'formatter': 'verbose',
            }
        },
        'loggers': {
            'django': {
                'handlers': ['console', 'django_log_file', 'django_errors_file'],
                'level': level,
                'propagate': False,
            },
            'django.db.backends': {
                'handlers': ['console', 'db_log_file'],
                'level': level,
                'propagate': False,
            },
            '': {
                'handlers': ['console', 'apps_log_file'],
                'level': level,
                'propagate': True,
            },
            'myapp_ui': {
                'handlers': ['console', 'myapp_ui_log_file'],
                'level': level,
                'propagate': True,
            },
            'api1': {
                'handlers': ['console', 'myapp_apis_log_file'],
                'level': level,
                'propagate': True,
            },
            'api2': {
                'handlers': ['console', 'myapp_apis_log_file'],
                'level': level,
                'propagate': True,
            },
            'api3': {
                'handlers': ['console', 'myapp_apis_log_file'],
                'level': level,
                'propagate': True,
            },
        },
    }
```

The error traceback:

```
[2023-02-01T03:18:26+0000] DEBUG [django.template: _resolve_lookup: 867] Exception while resolving variable 'name' in template 'unknown'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 100, in _get_response
    resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/newrelic/hooks/framework_django.py", line 613, in wrapper
    return _wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/newrelic/hooks/framework_django.py", line 601, in _wrapped
    result = wrapped(path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 575, in resolve
    raise Resolver404({'tried': tried, 'path': new_path})
django.urls.exceptions.Resolver404: {'tried': [[<URLResolver <URLPattern list> (admin:admin) 'admin/'>], 
[<URLResolver <module 'myapp_ui.urls' from '/myapp/src/myapp_ui/urls.py'> (None:None) '^myapp_ui/'>], 
[<URLResolver <module 'generic_apis.urls' from '/myapp/src/generic_apis/urls.py'> (None:None) '^generic_apis/'>], 
[<URLResolver <module 'api1.urls' from '/myapp/src/api1/urls.py'> (None:None) '^api1/'>], 
[<URLResolver <module 'api2.urls' from '/myapp/src/api2/urls.py'> (None:None) '^api2/'>], 
[<URLResolver <module 'api3.urls' from '/myapp/src/api3/urls.py'> (None:None) '^api3/'>], 
[<URLPattern '^static/(?P<path>.*)$'>]], 'path': ''}

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 828, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current[bit]
TypeError: 'URLResolver' object is not subscriptable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 836, in _resolve_lookup
    current = getattr(current, bit)
AttributeError: 'URLResolver' object has no attribute 'name'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 842, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current[int(bit)]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'name'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 847, in _resolve_lookup
    raise VariableDoesNotExist("Failed lookup for key "
django.template.base.VariableDoesNotExist: Failed lookup for key [name] in <URLResolver <module 'api2.urls' from '/myapp/src/api2/urls.py'> (None:None) '^api2/'>
```

I'm getting these `django.views.debug:technical_404_response` logs every time an API call is made. This might be because the Django API template does not contain a "name" attribute.

I have tried changing the format `'format': "[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s [%(name)s: %(funcName)s: %(lineno)s] %(message)s"` to `'format': "[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s [%(funcName)s: %(lineno)s] %(message)s"` but I need to log the `name` attribute for all other debugging purposes.

Please suggest a workaround to resolve the same.

(ETA 1)

`myapp/urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^myapp_ui/', include('myapp_ui.urls')),
    url(r'^generic_apis/',include('generic_apis.urls')),
    url(r'^api1/', include('api1.urls')),
    url(r'^api2/', include('api2.urls')),
    url(r'^api3/', include('api3.urls')),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
# STATIC_ROOT=staticfiles
# STATIC_URL='/static/'
```

`api2/urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^get_data/v0$', views.get_data_v0, name="get_data_v0"),
]
```

Comment: Can you share a project that reproduces this on GitHub?